# PHP MySQL alway gets false as return

Tags: php, mysql

i wrote some PHP stuff and iam stuck here:

```php
$mysql = new mysqli($MYSQL_HOST, $MYSQL_USER, $MYSQL_PASSWORD, $MYSQL_DATABASE);
$result = $mysql->query("SELECT `value` FROM `config` WHERE `config` = 'url' LIMIT 1");

var_dump($result);
```

The var dump always give me false. I cant fetch the result. I testet the connection, it works. Also i execute the SQL in phpmyadmin and it gives me the value back.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to match the `config` with string literal `'url'`. Is this supposed to be done?

Comment: Could you show us your tables with two or three example entries and your desired result of the query?

Comment: My Table looks like this http://666kb.com/i/d9ss9fez45rhy1oat.png

Comment: No pictures, thanks, but an sqlfiddle (together with an update to the question showing the desired result) would be OK

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/045a3

I want to geht the text value from the field value.

Comment: I could think of MySQL struggling with the names. Have you tried to explicitly name the column like `config.config` ?

Comment: I tried this, also i renamed the column config to conf.. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

RUn this code first, then run the query which display in the browser to the mysql apps (eg. phpmyadmin).

```
$mysql = new mysqli($MYSQL_HOST, $MYSQL_USER, $MYSQL_PASSWORD, $MYSQL_DATABASE);
$qry=""SELECT `value` FROM `config` WHERE `config` = 'url' LIMIT 1"";
die($qry);
$result = $mysql->query($qry);
```

You will know what the query error message.